# Extracting top and bottom quintile for each period

Tags: r, time-series

In my data set, there are 200 monthly returns of 500 stocks. I want to make two portfolios from it.First portfolio will consist of top 50 stocks for each period. Another portfolio consist of bottom 50 stocks for each period. The data is in xts format.I am first trying it for first period. Then will make a loop. But I am not able to extract it in last step. Please check my code

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
XSMOM<-managers
XSMOM<-XSMOM[-1:-60]
## making a empty winner matrix
winners<-matrix(0,200,50)
## extracting first period return
last_return<-XSMOM[1,]
## ordering the first period return in decreasing order
my_order<-order(last_return,decreasing = T)
## selecting top 50 stocks
Top_50<-my_order[1:50]
## extracting winners for first period
winners[1,]<-XSMOM[1,][Top_50]
```

Comment: Does `XSMOM[1, Top_50]` give you what you want?

Comment: @jay.sf Tnx solved